# How to handle multiple clicks

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

Before asking, I did a search, without success for me.

I have some trouble about trying to handle multiple clicks on buttons in my android app.

The problem is that when spamming the button, I navigate to the other fragment.
So spamming button causing navigation crash.

I tried a couple of solution, but no one of them that I found was working for me.
I tried to : 
 - disable the button 
 - handle with a state (`boolean`)

Actually, I have navigation crash "blblbl is unknown to this `navController`"
I expect that when I spam the button, the first time it works, but the other time, it's blocked.

Here some code :

```
override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem) = when (item.itemId) {
    R.id.action_next -> validateAndNavigateTo(R.id.action_intervention_product_fragment_to_intervention_summary_fragment)
    R.id.action_validate -> validateAndNavigateTo(getActionId())
    else -> {
        if (!isFromSummary) interventionProductViewModel.saveMemoryProductsInDatabase()
        interventionProductViewModel.emptyListSelectedChemicalProducts()
        super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }
}

private fun validateAndNavigateTo(actionId: Int): Boolean {
    if (validate()) {
        val bundle = Bundle().apply {
            putString(INTERVENTION_ID, interventionId)
            if (arguments?.getString(USE_CASE) != null) {
                putString(USE_CASE, arguments?.getString(USE_CASE))
                putString(FILTER_BY_FIELD_CODE_SERVER, arguments?.getString(FILTER_BY_FIELD_CODE_SERVER))
            }
            putString(FILTER_BY_FIELD_CODE_SERVER, arguments?.getString(FILTER_BY_FIELD_CODE_SERVER))
        }
        interventionProductViewModel.saveMemoryProductsInDatabase()
        getKoin().getOrCreateScope(SCOPE_FIELD).close()
        view?.findNavController()?.navigate(actionId, bundle)
    }
    return true
}
```

Thanks all for your help.

Comment: share some part of your code to clarify your problem

Comment: You can now see some code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code when you navigate from one destination to another. 

 The below code is in java, editor will automatically convert it into Kotlin once you copy and paste.

```
public static void navigate(View view, @IdRes int destination, @Nullable Bundle args, NavOptions navOptions) {
         try {
             Navigation.findNavController(view).navigate(destination, args, navOptions);
         } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
             Log.e(TAG, "Multiple navigation attempts handled here");
         }
    }
```

Comment: I already tried this, it works in some case, but its like hidding the error, and for my team that not the best choice/practice ..